# JQuery Live vs On

Tags: jquery

i have the below code which was working fine with Live

```
 $('.numbersonly').live('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
           (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
});
```

And i changed to On

```
 $('.numbersonly').on('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
           (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
});
```

But am getting script error in min.js file . Am i missing something?

Comment: kindly update to add the script error

Comment: Which jQuery version you are using??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegate event to parent of `.numbersonly` or `document` otherwise

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.numbersonly', function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
       (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind events with on, the events will be binded only for the Current DOM elements (that matching your selector)
So that is recommend , that use on ,  'after' domready event.

example:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
         ...
         $('selector').on('event',eventHandler(e){
             ...
         });
  });
```

If you use live, the events will binding to matched elements after modify the dom tree too.
(For example you load content with ajax)